# calling initialization code on view which was created by loading nib from file

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I loaded a view created by interface builder as follows:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];
MyView *myView = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

The view created in the nib also has a .h and .m UIView subclass associated with it.  I have initialization code within my .m source file.  What is the preferred method to call initialization code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use -awakeFromNib. This will be called the first time the class is deserialized from the nib.